# Does SharedViewModel violate Single Responsibility Principle?

Tags: android, design-patterns, android-viewmodel

I have one activity and 4 fragment, I have SharedViewModel which helps me to pass data from Activity to all other Fragments

```
                             Activity
                                |
                          SharedViewModel
                                |
         ----------------------------------------------------
         |               |                |                 |
      (Fragment A)   (Fragment B)     (Fragment C)    (Fragment D)
```

Now here you can see that SharedViewModel has Activity along with all Fragment's data. So, one SharedViewModel contain variables and functions of 5 different class, like variables such as LiveData, other database related functions or some network operation related functions.

1) only one function is used as a common to share data between all classes.

2) Other functions are individual functions of all other class.

so is this violate Single Responsibility Principle? If not then how?

Answer (score 1):

**Single Responsibility Principle** for **MVVM** can be referred for repository pattern from where you expose your data to UI using `ViewModel`.

So imagine that `ViewModel` is only responsible for *each request of data from UI to Repository* and *provide response back from Repository to UI back*.

On the other hand, Repository is only concerned with providing data back while eventually it doesn't matter whether it comes from local db or from API call.

So, that's how Single Responsibility can be derived for MVVM.

---

Now, for your architecture, it is *100%* okay as soon as your `SharedViewModel` just provides data updates to each UI *(Activity/Fragment)* which can be considered as common across all via `LiveData` that every component commonly shares & observes.

If you place a data holder *(`LiveData`)*/variable that can be considered as dependent for only one UI then you should use individual `ViewModel` for that UI,

so about second point, **"Other functions are individual functions of all other class."** I would suggest you to create `ViewModel`s related to your UI seperately & make `ShareViewModel` simple & tiny as possible so that you don't expose your one UI operations to others.

Comment: First all of thank you so much for your quick answer Jeel, so as per my understanding I can make 2 ViewModel for each View right? suppose one is CommonViewModel which is shared and others are ViewModel which are personal for each view right?